# POE without the Rpi Hat?

Tags: pi-3b+, poe

I have a raspberry pi 3b+ with the 4 PoE connectors. How can I power the Pi with Ethernet without buying the PoE Hat? Is there a link to a schematic for the PoE hat? I need a different board on top of my Pi.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a POE splitter: I’ve used the following with excellent results. Cheaper than a POE Hat to and leaves the GPIO pins free too!:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Y6M67F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1